# Game Development Stack Exchange swag for top users

Tags: discussion, swag

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Game Development Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Game Development Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### T-Shirt

[image: gamedev.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### Sticker

[image: gamedev.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Awesome, made my day.

Comment: Thanks! Tokens of appreciation are always welcome. Brought a smile to my face after a very rough week.

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much! Unexpected gifts are always awesome! :)

Comment: I have to say, I was pleasantly surprised when I received an email about this. Very cool! :)

Comment: :) Very cool stuff. I totally put AAGrapsas, though, instead of A.A. Grapsas; but, I figure you guys'll figure that one out! Really cool that you're doing this!! Much appreciated!

Comment: Oh noes! Huge kudos to jhocking though!

Comment: What about for the most amazingest new users? Like [Trevor Powell](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/7728/trevor-powell), [Valkea](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/6813/valkea) and... me? :P

Comment: @3nix we see you! http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers

Comment: Oh I almost missed it, didn't see the mail, thank you guys very much :)

Comment: status update ?

Comment: @will 6-8 weeks .. everything is in progress!

Comment: I realise this is an exceptional case. Still, with all due respect and congratulations, I point out that this still is not a question and those still are not answers. Ironically, this "question" implies that precisely _all of you_ ought to know better. Next time, just send the emails and leave the chatter to the chatroom?

Comment: @aku this is a perfectly acceptable topic for meta, see [meta-faq]

Comment: @Jeff I can't see your point. The FAQ encourages questions and discourages using the Meta as a "random discussion area". This is not a question. This is, however, a random discussion.

Comment: @aku it is a discussion about a promotion *benefiting the gamedev.se community* -- it is 100% absolutely on-topic. It directly affects at least 72 members of the gamedev community, and anyone else who would like to obtain gamedev swag from http://shop.stackexchange.com

Comment: Suggestion - maybe change the FAQ to allow announcements (at least from the management)? While I certainly have no problem with this Question (partly because I'm on page 2 :) I would say that it's an **announcement** (with feedback), not a true *discussion*. But there's not really a *better* place to put it, so I'd agree it belongs here.

Comment: Damn, if only I had started posting here a few weeks earlier I could have gotten one of these

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, is there any news on this? It is almost two month now.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, any news? It has been over two months now.

Comment: @hendrik afaik everything was mailed out about a week ago?

Comment: Mine arrived yesterday. Ahoy!

Comment: Mine too! Looks good.

Comment: Arrived. <3 And yes, it worked as designed, i.e, I haven't been active here for a while, but now I'm visiting again..

Comment: Yup, mine arrived too. Nice pens!

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, Yay! I finally got it.

Comment: and page 3 gets maybe just the shirt ;)?

Comment: Mine arrived a few days ago. Thanks! :)

Comment: Still haven't got mine :( I'm fairly certain I filled out the form. Any way to check?

Answer (score 3):

Very cool, thanks so much! It's fun being part of this community.

Comment: I just noticed that I should probably flag my own "answer", since it is more of a comment. But technically Jeff didn't post a question either :)

Comment: Everyone is using answers for feedback ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The form asks for user-name, but my user-name is not unique.  How are you going to match it all up?

<sup>Neat way to get the real names and addresses of your users</sup>

Comment: you can use the full URL of your user page if you like, that is unique

Comment: cool, I'll just submit again to be sure eh? how many goodie bags will I get?

Comment: I will not up-vote or down-vote anything from you Will while you have 1337 points!

Comment: You can upvote him here on meta, it doesn't effect his score.

Answer (score 3):

This is great. I was writing meta post about something like this: "hey why don't to make some promo t-shirts and send it to top users for free" a 3 month ago. Than i told myself to not be annoying and did not post anything.

And now! You just made it :-D. Great!

Also i would really appreciate some another color of t-shirt than classic "I'm typical IT guy black color" :). But still awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the store has *SO* shirt in white, but the gamedev shirts don't even seem to be on sale. And I was thinking of getting another one - guess it's an exclusive :(

Answer (score 2):

I might just be a little paranoid here but there is a voice inside saying something along these lines:

> When the internet offers freebies (with free global shipping and no strings attached) through an email which states that I must give out personal information to a link which goes to "spreadsheets.google.com"... I should proceed with caution.

Comment: I would be suspicious of this too, but it's StackExchange/Overflow we're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

*Just* got my package :) I don't know if I'm one of the first, or one of the *last*, but at least I can confirm they're shipping. Apparently the fulfillment company is called `ST Associates`, if you see a strange package in the mail. :) (Though there's also a "ref:Stackexchange" note on the label).

Comment: Yup, got mine too today. Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

And I thought that my score wasn't that high. Thank you guys! :D

Comment: One of the few advantages of being in a smaller community... On SO, there are 12K *pages* of users, I'd be somewhere around 11K.

Comment: @Cyclops If you look at a lot of them, they have 1 rep and no questions, no answers, no nothing. or maybe one poor question. There's about 5k pages of them.

Comment: @The Communist Duck, yes, I know, it was an *exaggeration*. :) In fact, it's actually 6K pages, roughly *half* of the users are 1-pointers. I once counted, to compare with UnityAnswers, to see if UA was just unlucky. But in both cases, it seems half the people just sign on once.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow this is awesome. I am so glad to be a part of this community.

<s>Is this going to be available for global shipping?</s> Just found the email, so it is.

Is there going to be a confirmation of order?

Answer (score 0):

Got my package today, thanks!  At first I thought, "I didn't order anything from EBay, did I?"

Comment: It's hard to find, but if you look closely at the label, there is a `ref:Stackexchange` line, even if it's an unknown 'from' address.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone in the UK got theirs yet? I'm still keeping my fingers crossed that "global shipping" included such backwater places as London, England...

Mine came yesterday! Wooo (Sep 24 UK)

Comment: I'm in Germany, and I got mine today.