# Washing Gamedev T-shirt

Tags: discussion, swag

Some of you have received your [swag packages](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/game-development-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users). Grats!

I just want to stress that, when you wash your gamedev.se t-shirt, **PLEASE** make sure you turn it inside out, use cold water and non-bleach detergent. We used digital printing on the black T, so it requires extra care.

We have received a few reports from our gaming.se community that the design faded after one wash.(which isn't normal, since my gaming shirt looks fine after many washes). Anyway, just want to bring this to your attention.

Comment: There was *also* a small note inside the thank-you letter, about washing the shirt inside-out. I guess people don't read manuals *or* instruction sheets. :) Btw, the shirts are great, very comfortable fabric.

Comment: @Jin, it was a really good idea to put the small items into a plastic bag. My envelop was heavily damaged and had a large whole at the side. So the inner bag prevent the things from falling out. Luckily the content was unharmed.

Comment: @Jin, could you define cold as a temperature range?

Comment: @eBusiness as long as it's not on hot or warm then it's OK. I know different washer brands' actual temperature settings may vary

Comment: @Jin I am familiar with neither the term 'hot' nor 'warm'. I can convert from those strange American temperatures, but not from ambiguous words. So far all I know is that 40 deg Celsius is too warm.

Comment: @eBusiness I think tap water temperature is what "cold" setting in on my washer, I estimate it's about 18-22 C.

Comment: @eBusiness A 30° wash is a cold wash. Damn I can't believe I'm posting this on GameDev...

Comment: Or you could just not wash it and leave it in its pristine original state.